# Выборка отсутствующего значения

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы A, B. 
Структура таблицы A.

```
*A.id
A.other
```

Структура таблицы B

```
*B.id
B.A_id
B.uid
```

Необходимо получить из таблицы A данные при условии что в таблице B у нас нет нужного значения в uid (B.uid).
К примеру

```
A
id  other
1   lol
2   foo
3   bar

B
id  A_id    uid
1   1       2
2   1       3
3   1       1
4   2       1
5   2       2
```

и необходимо состряпать запрос который при uid=3 вернет значения A с id 2 и 3.
Понимаю что надо юзать join. Пытался сделать запросы на подобии

```
SELECT * FROM `A` INNER JOIN `B` ON (`A`.`id` = `B`.`A_id`) where `B`.`uid` !=3
```

но все тщетно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, что нужно:

```
select a.* from a left join (select a_id from b where uid=3) X 
on a.id = X.a_id 
where a_id is null
```

[Внешние соединения](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_these_sly_outer_joins.html)

Answer (score 2):

LEFT JOIN спасёт отца русской демократии.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#LEFT_OUTER_JOIN